# Питон. Не получается сравнить два числа

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

Надо найти число в списке. Это число в списке точно есть. А программа говорит, что нет. В чем может быть причина?

`Val` - это значение, которое считывается из ячейки `excel`, `line[1]` - строка, `line[2]` - это третий элемент (представляет собою список) в списке `line`. Надо найти значение ячейки в списке `line[2]`. `Len` - количество ячеек в `excel`.

```
i = 0
r = 3
for line in list_trunk:
    for itm in line[2]:
        while i < len:
            val = sheet.cell(row=r, column=3).value
            if int(itm) == int(val):
                cell = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2)
                cell.value = line[1]
             r += 1
             i += 1
```

Известно, что значение `itm` точно есть в 3-м столбце `excel`, а код не хочет записывать это значение во 2-й столбец.

```
line = [name1, name2, [число1, число2, число3]]
```

Это список, который формируется из текстового файла

Comment: А что такое `val = sheet.cell(row=r, column=3).value` и какой список на входе `list_trunk` можете немного добавить для наглядности, Вы уверены что необходимо делать несколько циклов и для этой задачи не подойдут стандартные методы списков? Типа определения индекса эл-та или его количество и т.п.

Comment: val - это считывается значение из ячейки xlsx,строчка №r, столбик №3 с помощью библиотеки openpyxl.     list_trunk[0] = [name, discription, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], list_trunk = [ list_trunk[0],  list_trunk[1], ...]. надо стравнить значение val с этими числами 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

Comment: Т.е. список чисел всегда последний эл-т вложенных списков? И там всегда целые числа?

Comment: да, именно так, это номера оборудования

Answer (score 3):

Не работал с `excel` может это как-то поможет:

```
for line in list_trunk:
    val = sheet.cell(row=r, column=3).value  # тут мне не понятно что происходит
    # должно быть '.value' или '.value()'?
    print(val, type(val))
    try:
        print([line[-1].index(i) for i in val])  # предположил что это итерируемый объект
    except:
        print(line[-1].index(val))
```

Попробуйте это и напишите что выводит код, должен выдать индекс эл-та